# Returning multiple results in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, return, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to learn more about what it can do and how to use it.

is it possible to return multiple results as a result of a calculation?

I am working on a calculator for a class project. What I would like it to do is  return 3 values on my page:

`Interest rate`

`total amount borrowed` and
`monthly repayment`

So far I have managed to get it to display monthly repayment in a div on the page, but I would like to be able to show all 3 on the page as a result of the one calculation.

Is this possible?

Here is what I have come up with so far:
HTML:
`<p><input  type="button" onclick="main();" value="Calculate"></p>`

JavaScript:

```
function main()
{

var userInput1 = 0;
var userInput2 = 0;
var displayResult;


userInput1 = document.getElementById("loan_amount").value;
userInput1 = parseFloat(userInput1);
userInput2 = document.getElementById("loan_term").value;
userInput2 = parseFloat(userInput2);

displayResult = calcLoan(userInput1,userInput2);
document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML=displayResult;

}

function calcLoan(userInput1,userInput2)
{
var interest =0;


    if (userInput1 <1000)
    {
    alert("Please enter a value above £1000")
    }
    else if (userInput1 <= 10000)
    {
    interest = 4.25 + 5.5;
    }
    else if (userInput1 <= 50000)
    {
    interest = 4.25 + 4.5;
    }
    else if (userInput1 <= 100000)
    {
    interest = 4.25 + 3.5;
    }
    else 
    {
    interest = 4.25 + 2.5;
    }


var totalLoan = 0;  


    totalLoan = userInput1 +(userInput1*(interest/100))*userInput2; 

var monthlyRepayment = 0;
var monthly;


    monthlyRepayment = totalLoan/(userInput2*12);
    monthly=monthlyRepayment.toFixed(2);


    alert("Interest Rate = " + interest + "%" +" "+"Total Loan amount = " + "£"+ totalLoan +" "+ "Your monthly repayment is = " + " " + "£"+ monthly);

return monthly; 

}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create variables with multiple custom fields and pass them between functions. So, your functions should look like this:

```
function main()
{
    ...

    displayResult = calcLoan(userInput1,userInput2);
    document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML = displayResult.interest;
    document.getElementById("Result2").innerHTML = displayResult.totalLoan;
    document.getElementById("Result3").innerHTML = displayResult.monthly;
}

function calcLoan(userInput1,userInput2)
{
    ...

    alert("Interest Rate = " + interest + "%" +" "+"Total Loan amount = " + "£"+ totalLoan +" "+ "Your monthly repayment is = " + " " + "£"+ monthly);

    var result;
    result.interest = interest;
    result.totalLoan = totalLoan;
    result.monthly = monthly;

    return result; 
}
```

And don't forget to add div elements with IDs Result1, Result2 and Result3.

```
<div id="Result1"></div>
<div id="Result2"></div>
<div id="Result3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go and let you know

Comment: I tried this method. The error console gives the error "result id undefined" referring to `var result;
    result.interest = interest;
    result.totalLoan = totalLoan;
    result.monthly = monthly;`

Comment: OK. Change `var result;` to `var result = [];`. Now it should work.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! What do the `[]` mean?
Also, if i wanted to include a checkbox, which did a slightly different calculation (added 5%) would I put it in a separate function block or within the `calcLoan` block?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try some JavaScript OOP. A function can return multiple values quite easily. There are several ways to do it. Try to read this: http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/ and this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/